# Is it safe to extend an outlet off of a series of light fixtures?

Tags: electrical, safety, wiring

So the tldr here is I need an outlet in my basement but I don't want to burn my house down in the process. I believe I did the math correct here but I'd just like to know if there's anything I'm not considering in this specific scenario

The black is existing equipment and the red is what I'm planning on adding in. I'm pretty sure the bulbs down there are all low wattage LED bulbs and the machine actually draws ~1170 watts but I wanted to over plan this just in case.

Am I missing anything here?

[image]

Comment: Are these "real" 60W bulbs? If they are 60W incandescent bulbs, replace them with LED, which vary but typically use on the order of 10W. If they are 60W LED bulbs, that is a *lot* of light.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact yeah they're currently LED bulbs but I wanted to factor them in my numbers as 60w bulbs in case in the future someone sticks one in there. Plan for the worst, hope for the best kinda mentality I guess

Comment: 1200w is the going to be the max load on a 15 amp circuit so you are “not over planning” by code. If those are 60 w fixtures you are supposed to use those values and remember lighting is a continuous load 125% of actual, if your machine is motor driven it two will require 125% also so would it meet code? Probably not on a 15a will it work? Possibly, motor loads take 3-5x to start , so if you turn all the lights on and then start the machine if the breaker holds it could work. Now one last thing if you have a federal pacific stab lock breaker panel it would be a good idea to replace that 1st

Comment: Before you do too much work, best check to make sure that you have a continuous path through those light fixtures of hot, neutral, and ground connections.  I.e. make sure none of those fixtures your planning on using are switched and only switched power goes through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### We use VA not watts.

The difference is, watts is the part of the sine-wave that the load actually uses... but VA is the whole sinewave the wiring must deliver (for the load to use parts of it).  VA is the number you must calculate on.

VA = volts x amps.

You rely on the equipment nameplate of the UL-Listed equipment for the VA and amps that it draws.  If you ever see equipment that says e.g. "12A, 1170 watts", thats what's going on. 12A implies 1440 VA, and both are true. VA is 1440 and watts is 1170.

If the equipment is not UL-listed (or CSA or ETL), don't plug it into North American power.  For a Bitcoin miner this is probably a power supply module; they make UL listed versions of those.

Power Factor is the ratio between watts and VA.  So if you have a 1170W supply that is 1440 VA, then the Power Factor is 1170/1440 or 0.81. Poor power factor requires you to provision more power to it. You can get a better power factor by buying a better power supply.

PF typically gets worse at low power levels, but we only care about the VA or amps at max power level.

### 125% derate for *continuous loads*

Which is a load that will run 3 hours or more, or certain loads (heaters, lights, EVSE) that are required to calculate as continuous loads.

You calculate the load on a circuit based on 125% of the *continuous loads* + 100% of the non-continuous loads.

Your Bitcoin miner is a continuous load. We can't do anything with the 1170W or 1300W figure, because this doesn't tell us what the VA is.

### If you'll be doing this regularly, power up.

Since you plan to do this regularly and on an increasing scale, you really ought to have a pro come in and wire in some dedicated circuits.  Wiring is cheap, fires are expensive.  Most PC-like power supplies cheerfully work on 120V and 240V both (and may even have better PF on 240V), and in that case consider using 240V power.  [The US is a 240V country](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4) and we have a variety of sockets specifically for 240V power. They wire almost the same as normal circuits.

[image]

Comment: "Apparent power" is the term for the total going through the wires (given in VA), not just consumed by the load (given in W), if you want to read up on that.

Comment: Thanks or the detailed info. I have two 1000w Gold PSU running the machine, plugged into a surge protector and that's plugged into a meter. The meter output is 1170. (link to power supply https://www.amazon.com/EVGA-Supernova-Modular-Warranty-220-G5-1000-X1/dp/B07WMTD41Z/ref=asc_df_B07WMTD41Z/?tag=&linkCode=df0&hvadid=385191927323&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=8367934502300758556&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9015337&hvtargid=pla-827675245428&ref=&adgrpid=82240853001&th=1)

Comment: They're just computer power supplies. I imagine if they draw too much power, the 15 amp breaker would trip wouldn't it?

Comment: @AnthonyRussell we don't *rely* on circuit breakers popping because that creates a single point of failure, and because *a lot* of people react to annoying trips by enlarging the breaker (without enlarging the wires - bad).  The meter is stating watts, which is useless for this. The nameplate clearly says 15A at 120V and 8A @ 240V.  That derates to 18.75A@120V and 10A @ 240V.  You need 20A circuits - one unit per 120V circuit or two per 240V circuit.   By the way we can see this is 1800/1920 VA, kinda awful for only 1000W. Good power factor costs, but saves you money on wiring.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine thanks for the info. I had my electrician come out today and install 3 dedicated 20 amp circuits.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan will work. The outlet will need to be a GFCI since it's in a basement, probably unfinished. If those are LED bulbs, you might see some dimming/flickering when the machine is stating/running. We see all sorts of problems about LED bulbs acting up... so heads up on that.

Any chance of you just running a new circuit from the breaker box to your new outlet location?

Comment: That is the plan actually. I've been running a POC mining rig down there. After the ethereum 2.0 merge I'm going to gauge profitability on other coins and make a choice to build out a much larger mining operation down there. When that happens, I'm going to be upgrading the breaker (probably the box too lol)